# Send data from BroadcastReceiver to Activity in background(without starting)

Tags: java, android

I have this receiver class, it' registered in my MainActivity, it's supposed to count unlocks.

**My goal**

I want to make it work even when the app itself is not running(the receiver is never unregistered). It should get the amount of unlocks to the main activity without starting/restarting the activity.

**My problem**

I have no idea how to do that. As you can see I have tried to do it with `SharedPreferences`, but it didn't work, the receiver works fine and gets broadcasts, I just don't want it to start everytime.

```java
public class UnlockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private int count = 0;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static final String TAG = "UnlockReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("label", 0);
        count = preferences.getInt("tag", 0);

        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
                count++;
                editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("tag", count).commit();
                Log.d(TAG, "unlock registered");
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("tag", count);
                context.sendBroadcast(i);
            }
        } else {
            if (!keyguardManager.isDeviceLocked()) {
                count++;
                editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("tag", count).commit();
                Log.d(TAG, "unlock registered");
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("tag", count);
                context.sendBroadcast(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The approach must be the next: register the receiver in the manifest, when the user unlock the screen, then fetch the saved data in store an increase it, by default the data is zero.  If you want to update your screen at the same time (app is in foreground) you need to do a reactive approach, notifying the change to update the UI.  For example using Observer pattern, flow, livedata...

Comment: @ManuelMato there is a problem, in the docs it says that since android oreo you can no longer register certain broadcasts in the manifest(which is the case with this), you need to register it programmatically and I did that and it still doesn't work. I don't need to update it live, but I just want it to count even if the app is closed, can you help?

Comment: the option is to use the BOOT_COMPLETED receiver and when the device is booted, then register your broadcast

Comment: so I should register the unlock reciever on boot and the boot receiver in the manifest and then it should work?

Comment: Yes, because the boot receiver is possible to register it in the manifest, so when the user boot the phone, then you register the unlock receiver